# How do I view the actual string variable of a variable/constant?

Tags: debugging, swift, parse-platform

Environment: Debugging Parse return object within Xcode 6.1

I can see the text within the object structure but can't adequately view its assigned variable.

Here's the code:

```
func retrieveAllMediaFromParse() {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

        let myData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: kParseMedia)
        myData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in
            if !(error != nil){
                //  for object in objects {
                let myObject = objects[0] as PFObject
                let format = myObject.objectForKey("format") as String
                let access = myObject.objectForKey("access") as String
                let media = myObject.objectForKey("media") as String
                let owner = myObject.objectForKey("owner") as String
                let text = myObject.objectForKey("text") as String
                let thumbNail = myObject.objectForKey("thumbnail") as NSString
            }
        }
    });

  }
let text = myObject.objectForKey("text") as String
```

When I take the 'po' of the command string I get the correct interpretation:
[image]

However, when I do the same for the assigned variable (constant), I get the following:

[image]

How do I view the variable/constant to display the actual string?

Comment: What about printing the values via code using `println(text)`?

Comment: yah... that does work.
...would like to merely use the debugger though.

Answer (score 0):

When program is paused in the debugger, you can find the values of PFObject fields by going to the `estimatedData` line in the debugger.

[image: debugger]